How do I fix this unmet requirement for building Unity in TeamCity?
I am trying to use TeamCity to build my Unity application.  I am kicking off my builds via GitHub integration.  It auto-detects everything just fine, but when I try to find a compatible agent, they are all incompatible.  They all have the reason:
Unmet requirements: Exists=>unity\.path\.2022\.3\.15.* exists
Under my agent parameters, it says I have the configuration parameter:
unity.path.2022.3.12 /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.12f1
I suspect this is the problem.  How do I switch to Unity 2022.3.15 (as I am using) instead of 2022.3.12?  Or is this not the actual issue?
